# React protected route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code :

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (<Route {...rest} render={(props) => (isAuthenticated() === true ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/login' /> )} />)
}
```

but i dont understand how this works.. I call it like :

```
<PrivateRoute exact path = '/home' component={Home}></PrivateRoute>
```

it works , I just dont understand it. Where is props being passed in ? What is component: Component.

I would appreciate if someone could explain how this components works.

Comment: You pass the component in the `render` parameter in `Route`. So if your `isAuthenticated` method returns true then `render` will be provided whatever component you passed otherwise it get the `Redirect` component and hence redirect the user to login. If you pass any other props to the `PrivateRoute` those will be passed to the `Route` component using rest parameter (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`component: Component` is [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

You could re write it in the following way:

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  const Component = props.component;
  //shallow copy props, can also do {...props}
  const rest = Object.assign({},props);
  //delete component property from rest
  //  this will not affect props becaus of the shallow copy
```

The react-router Route component will take a props.component and renders that component with all props passed to Route minus the props.component.

You create a `PrivateRoute` that does the same but instead of rendering the component passed in props directly, it will render Route and pass a render prop to it that is a component created on the fly `()=>jsx`. Route will render this component for you.